# Can we rely on Buddha's quotes found on internet?

Tags: the-buddha

I found many quotes on internet but if we'd think we do not find any reference in any scripture so do we need to ignore them as they are possibly fake quotes?

I found such:

> "Three things cannot be long hidden: the sun, the moon, and the truth."

I can see search generate result by this site ['fakebuddhaquotes.com'](http://fakebuddhaquotes.com/three-things-cannot-be-long-hidden-the-sun-the-moon-and-the-truth/)

> “Better than a thousand hollow words, is one word that brings peace.”

So are we supposed to ignore if they are fake and if not, what is second quote's meaning?

Comment: As the Buddha once said, "_In the entire history of humanity, by far the worst source of reliable quotations from me or anyone else for that matter, is the bloomin' Internet_". :-)  Actually, there are perhaps two exceptions. [Fake Buddha Quotes](http://fakebuddhaquotes.com) as you suggest, at least for finding out when something is bogus, is one. The other, not specific to Buddhism, is [Quote Investigator](http://quoteinvestigator.com) and it's superb. And then there are always Google searches starting with "site:accesstoinsight.org"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the same site -- http://fakebuddhaquotes.com/better-than-a-thousand-hollow-words-is-one-word-that-brings-peace/ -- the author identifies the second quote as a slightly inaccurate or poetic translation of the [100th verse of the Dhammapada](http://www.tipitaka.net/tipitaka/dhp/verseload.php?verse=100):

> Sahassamapi ce vaca
>   anatthapadasamhita
>   ekam atthapadam seyyo
>   yam sutva upasammati.
>
> 100. Better than a thousand words that are senseless and unconnected with the realization of Nibbana, is a single word of sense, if on hearing it one is calmed.

That too is not a literal translation into English -- http://www.tipitaka.net/tipitaka/dhp/index.php says they refer to the commentary if the literal meaning is vague or unintelligible or perplexing -- they added to the translation the phrase "unconnected with the realization of Nibbana" to clarify the difference between what they called senseless and sensible, i.e. between *anattha­pada­saṃhitā* and *atthapadam*.

[Here is](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/dhp/dhp.08.budd.html) maybe a more literal translation:

> 100. Better than a thousand useless words is one useful word, hearing which one attains peace.

Note that's close to the version you quoted in the OP (it's so close that I don't see why what you quoted is listed as a "fake" quote, instead of being listed among the "real" quotes).

If you still don't understand it, I recommend the commentary/story which accompanies each verse ([see here](http://www.tipitaka.net/tipitaka/dhp/verseload.php?verse=100)), and/or reading the whole chapter of the Dhammapada ([see here](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/dhp/dhp.08.budd.html)).

Comment: I also supposed thousand words as praying or recite something.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to http://fakebuddhaquotes.com/ there is also http://www.realbuddhaquotes.com/ which claim the quotes are verified. You can get inspired by the real thing.

Answer (score 0):

Does it really even matter who wrote them? If it works for you great, if not then ignore it. As far as I know The Buddha never meant for his teachings to turn into a religion which people blindly follow. The same can be said about Jesus. Take what resonates as truth for you and avoid becoming a sheeple.

Comment: [Avoid invalidating the question, with answers of the form "That's the wrong question..."](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/61/254)

Comment: Nicely expressing two important teachings a) the three/four dharma seals (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_Dharma_Seals) (any teaching, regardless of the teacher, is Buddha Dharma if it has these marks), and b) tactfulness (taught in the Lotus Sutra and the Sutra of Inumerable Meanings - some teachings may work for you, some may not).